# Email sent in PHP with no body and no attachment

Tags: php, email

I want to send a Word file as attachment using PHP and the email is being sent, but with no body and a noname attachment is sent.

Here is the code:

```
$website=getwebsite($id);
  //define the receiver of the email
$to = $email;
//define the subject of the email
$subject = "order- ".getorderid($id);
//create a boundary string. It must be unique
//so we use the MD5 algorithm to generate a random hash
$random_hash = md5(date('r', time()));
//define the headers we want passed. Note that they are separated with \r\n
$headers = "From: order@$website\r\nReply-To: order@$website";
//add boundary string and mime type specification
$headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\"";
//read the atachment file contents into a string,
//encode it with MIME base64,
//and split it into smaller chunks
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($file)));
//define the body of the message.
//echo $file;
ob_start(); //Turn on output buffering
?>


--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?> 
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>"

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?> 
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Hello World!!!
This is simple text email message.

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?> 
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<p>Dear Customer,</p>

<p>Please find attached your requested paper.</p>
<p>

Thanks & Regards</p>

<?php echo $website?>  Papers Team

 </p>

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>--



--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?> 
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-word; name="plagerism.doc"; 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 
Content-Disposition: attachment 

<?php echo $attachment; ?>
--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>--

<?php
//copy current buffer contents into $message variable and delete current output buffer
$message = ob_get_clean();
//send the email
$mail_sent = mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
//if the message is sent successfully print "Mail sent". Otherwise print "Mail failed"
echo $mail_sent ? "Mail sent" : "Mail failed";
```

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to compose the mime yourself, you could try using this class, saves you alot of headakes: http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/files/phpmailer%20for%20php5_6/

Answer (score 1):

If you view the source of the email sent you'll see that the boundary hashes you're using are mangled. Here's one for example:

```
--PHP-alt-add441e2865420b692613d7fContent-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"
```

You'll need to make sure the boundary hash is on its own line.

So where you have this:

```
--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

Either add a hard newline in the code like this:

```
--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>

Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

Or add it into the code that prints out the boundary hash, like so:

```
--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash."\n" ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.html